# Бешенный Internet Explorer

Tags: windows

Доброго всем мученикам ОС Windows
Год назад не вытерпел (заставили) поставил win7 64 bit
Теперь при нажатии e-mail в любом браузере выскакивает миллиард окошек Internet Explorer'a и ложит комп на лопатки, он пыхтит, лежит, но дышит. От того, что он дышит, толку мало, надо что-бы ещё и работал.
Как быТЬ?
Ссылается этот всеми "любимый" браузер на неправильно установленный клиент.Клиент у меня The Bat (использую с начала 2000-х). Поэтому прежде чем советовать, про его настройки, подумайте разобрался я ли в них или нет (The Bat самая моя любимая программулинка для почты).
А вот как быть с настройками Windows программ по умолчанию?Ведь там везде на mailto прописан TheBat.
Неужели и тут заставляют перейти на всеми "любимый" OutLoock? (могу ошибаться в его названии, но как-то так он звучит).

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что Вы не предоставили абсолютно никаких сведений относительно того, ЧТО Вы уже попробовали сделать...
 1. Пуск - Программы по умолчанию - Задание программ по умолчанию. Там найдите The Bat! и жмите "Использовать по умолчанию"
 2. Пуск - Программы по умолчанию - Сопоставление типов файлов или протоколов конкретным программам. Там ищите MAILTO, описание - "URL:MailTo-протокол". Если стоит не The Bat!, жмите "Изменить программу" и меняйте на нужное.
 3. Можно пошукать в реестре. Ветка HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command. Смотрите, что там в значениях, какая программа.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй наоборот, сбросить все настройки программ по умолчанию. Как-то это должно быть возможно. Посмотри на реакцию. Или посмотри, что будет если по умолчанию включить использование другого мэйл клиента. Не исключаю, что Мышь сама использует ИЕ для каких-то своих нужд.